# How to customize a scrollbar color?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar

I found some sample code like below, for trying to customize a scrollbar color:

```
HBRUSH CMainFrame::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)       
{ 
   HBRUSH hbr = CFrameWnd::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor); 

   if(nCtlColor==CTLCOLOR_SCROLLBAR) 
      return m_brColor; 

   return hbr; 
}
```

I found that the following code does not work:

```
procedure TForm1.WMCTLColor(var msg: TWMCTLCOLOR); message WM_CTLCOLOR;
```

How can I do it in Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `WM_CTLCOLOR` message in the native api. Instead you can use `CN_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR` control notification, which is send to child controls by the VCL in response to the API's [`WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
type
  TScrollBar = class(TScrollBar)
  protected
    procedure WMCtlColor(var Message: TWMCtlColorScrollbar); message CN_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR;
  end;

procedure TScrollBar.WMCtlColor(var Message: TWMCtlColor);
begin
  Message.Result := CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
end;
```

Or, if you don't want to derive a new control, provided the scrollbar is placed on the form:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  protected
    procedure WMCtlColorScrollbar(var Message: TWMCtlColorScrollbar);
      message WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR;
    ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.WMCtlColorScrollbar(var Message: TWMCtlColorScrollbar);
begin
  if Message.ChildWnd = ScrollBar1.Handle then
    Message.Result := CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
end;
```

Comment: I've try, but it doesn't work. Does it only work when my form has the TScrollBar? My demo code only has a TMemo with ScrollBar set to ssBoth

Comment: Clearly you need to attach the code to the right window! I can't see any mention of TMemo in the question. How did you expect us to know about that?

Comment: @Leo - David is right, the code you give in the question is for a scrollbar control, which you can find in the standard component tool palette of the IDE. A memo with scrollbars is a window with `WS_VSCROLL` and `WS_HSCROLL` styles, there're no separate  scrollbar controls in the memo. Neither the code you gave in the question, or the code in this answer will work for such a case.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading, and i though the case should be simple enough to state my question, and i just wanna know if the WM_CTLCOLOR work for normal controls in Delphi, such as TMemo or TStringGrid or any other one with built-in scrollbars. And seems that the Windows Message only work for TScrollBar in Delphi, and then thank you two guys

Comment: @David, i think you're understanding me that i'm trying to find a way to custom the color of the scrollbars of a generic controls in Delphi, such as TMemo, TStringGrid, TListView or TListBox, etc. I don't want to disable the built-in scrollbar and replace with mine, but just want to custom the built-in one, but so far, i got nothing

Comment: @Leo It's no good giving the crucial details in comments. Please edit the question so that it includes these details.

Comment: @Leo - It's not possible to use custom colors in scrollbars of standard controls by processing any WM_CTLCOLORxxx message. I can put this information in the answer if you like if you edit the question to ask that.

Answer (score 1):

This improvement avoids the memory leak by the repeated calling of CreateSolidBrush()

```
{ TMyScrollBar }
//******************************************************************************
constructor TMyScrollBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FHBrush := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(FBackColor));
end;

//******************************************************************************
destructor TMyScrollBar.Destroy;
begin
  DeleteObject(FHBrush);
  inherited;
end;

//******************************************************************************
procedure TMyScrollBar.SetBackColor(const Value: Tcolor);
begin
  FBackColor := Value;
  DeleteObject(FHBrush);
  FHBrush := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(FBackColor));
end;

//******************************************************************************
procedure TMyScrollBar.WMCtlColor(var Message: TWMCtlColorScrollbar);
begin
  Message.Result := FHBrush;
end;
```